# How do you add knowledge to LLMs

Tags: neural-networks, language-models, chatgpt

I recently heard an interesting comment from a gentleman on YouTube and it made sense instantly.

To paraphrase he explained that "fine-tuning" an LM is not necessarily adding knowledge to a model - it is rather teaching that model to do or suggest things in the style of the fine-tuning data.

So then my question is what if one does not want to change the model too much - just wants to make a model aware of a new set of data i.e.: a companies internal domain knowledge? Is there a recommended strategy?

Edit: My thought is some sort of distillation where you train a smaller or same model against itself - plus the additional data.

Comment: They are tunable.  Try treating them like a machine learner (they are) and augmenting their training.  Remember that in moving toward your stuff, they likely move away from their center, whatever that is.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZW1E017VEc&t=2112s

Comment: @EngrStudent That's a great interview. I has started it a while back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at llamaindex or langchain for information injection in the promt of the llm: https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

This retrieve-augment-generate (RAG) works without Finetuning/prolonged pre-training but comes with the cost of having to pay for the additional tokens in your "pre-promt" which is where you inject your new information

Also note that

1. pretraining or fine-tuning modifies the parameters $\theta$ of your neural net $f_\theta(x)$.
2. RAG on the other hand improves/modifies the input $x$ supplied to your model.

Comment: Are you taking about pre-prompts - and isn't that limited to max tokens which is not a lot currently?

Comment: Yes it is pre-promts and yes those are limited to max_tokens. If the rumours are true, for gpt4 we have 32000 max_tokens when they finally release it fully. This would be ~ 64000 words. This is more than many books have. Still it would be costly but Moore's law is with us, so costs per token will only drop!

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 8):

From [LIMA: Less Is More for Alignment](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.11206) (2023) by
Chunting Zhou et al.:

> These results strongly suggest that **almost all knowledge in large language models is learned during pretraining**, and only limited instruction tuning data is necessary to teach models to produce high quality output.

Remains prolonged pre-training and adding information in the prompt, as [Ggjj11](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/298651/ggjj11) suggested.

Answer (score 4):

The common way is through providing a context to a prompt. GPT type of bots' APIs allow for providing large amount of text for a context, e.g. 64K in a bot that I use. Also look up retrieval-augmented generation ([RAG](https://research.ibm.com/blog/retrieval-augmented-generation-RAG)).

The way I use this in my teaching is by supplying the text of my slides and lecture notes to the bot when conversing with it. So that a bot can use the context to come up with better answers than a general bot.

Comment: Just curious if the large context is only available through api calls. I use ChatGpt and the UI does not allow very many words.  Or perhaps, the large context is only allowed through system chat through the api as well.